# Creating a view of a webform submitted contents

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-webform

I need to display my Webform submitted results in a view. I am using Drual 7,Webform module and views. Is there any way to filter it to a view.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webform 7.x-4.0-alpha8 released just a few days ago at https://drupal.org/node/2023489 has more Views support built in. You can choose the submission data value that you want to see in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create view with show:-webform submission & then you can take 
Webform submission data: All values & Webform submission data: Value (second name) field in field area of view.